# Can the App Store send me an alert when a new review is posted?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

My company has 6 apps in the App Store. I want to know if there is an easy way to be alerted when a new review is posted in the App Store. Is there a program that can do this easily, or will I have to log in to the App Store each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this [AppSales Mobile](https://github.com/futuretap/AppSales-Mobile) on github, thanks to futuretap.

This app can download App Store reviews to your iPhone. I think it won't be hard for you to figure out the "Alert" part.

Answer (score 0):

There's also this:

http://www.appannie.com/

Not an app, but still very useful.